# Android - Fully transparent status bar with non transparent navigation bar

Tags: android, statusbar, transparent

I have been looking for a way to re-color the navigation bar while the status bar is fully transparent (not translucent). 
Getting the status bar to be completely transparent requires the layout flags to be set to NO_LIMITS but that also makes the navigation bar lose its color. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need the status bar text to be dark, the following works.

```
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

And change the navigation bar color as @JaviChaqués suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this:

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/your_color</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/your_color</item>
```

Comment: Yeah that’s one way I guess, but I’m looking for a way to let the NO_LIMITS flag only work for the status bar. So actually setting a flag to the window that doesn’t affect the navigation bar