# Dark-text transparent status bar with opaque navigation bar

Tags: android, android-view, statusbar, android-windowmanager, android-window

#### Wait, it is not a duplicate

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38025865/android-fully-transparent-status-bar-with-non-transparent-navigation-bar), but not addressing dark-text status bar.

#### What I want to do

I want to achieve 3 things **at the same time**:

1. Transparent status bar (Not hiding it!)
2. Dark-text status bar
3. Opaque (or black) navigation bar (which *does not let activity content inflate underneath it*)

#### What I have tried

The solution

```
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

can only achieve 1 and 3;

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311321/7870874) can only achieve 1 and 2;

And the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33509124/7870874) can only achieve 2 and 3....

#### The Question

So is there a way to achieve all 1, 2 an 3?!

Comment: `The solution here can only achieve 1 and 2` But in that answer navigation bar is transparent and activity's content is drawn beneath of it. Whereas you have told that you want `Opaque (or black) navigation bar (which does not let activity content inflate underneath it)`. You requirement is not quite clear.

Comment: My requirement is clear and you have already got it, I want opaque navigation bar but that answer can only achieve transparent navigation bar. Where is the contradiction?

Comment: Now I see, my fault

Comment: @azizbekian Don't mind, your answer worked like a charm!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

In activity's `onCreate()`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
```

Will result in this:

[image]