# How to make the status bar completely transparent with dark text color with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-statusbar

I use Kotlin to create an android app, I would like to know how to make the status bar completely transparent with dark text color with Kotlin
I seen the following soltuion but not work for me 
[Dark-text transparent status bar with opaque navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49296468/dark-text-transparent-status-bar-with-opaque-navigation-bar)
Here's my following code :

```
   if (VERSION.SDK_INT in 19..20) {
            setWindowFlag(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, true)
        }
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        }
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            setWindowFlag(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, false)
            window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
        }
```

Here's the custom style in style.xml:

```
<style name="MyStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And my xml code :

<.....    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" ....>

```
 <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="189dp"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/MyStyle" ....>
```

I want to know where's the problem in my code and How can I correct it to get the status bar completely transparent with dark text color

Comment: From API 23 you can set `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR`, try adding this to systemUiVisibility

Comment: I Try it, not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to follow three steps.

1. Update your style.xml and main theme

   ```xml
   <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
   ```
2. In your main xml add

   ```xml
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   ```
3. In your activity before `setcontView` add

   ```java
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
       Window w = getWindow();
       w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
   }
   ```

Comment: Yes, Than you, It work now 
But the navigation bar is hide now, How to show it

Comment: <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>